Error Connecting MongoDB with JDBC: CommandNotFound for 'sqlGetResultSchema'
I am using MongoDB docker image mongo:4.4 and is working fine with DBeaverEE (MongoDB) and Robo 3T.
I am trying to connect with MongoDB with JDBC using jaydebeapi.connect(...), also I have put all related jars (such as mongodb-jdbc-2.1.4.jar and mongodb-driver-sync-4.7.1.jar).
My Code:
I added {username}:{password} in a string as it gave me a null username error without it.
driver_name = "com.mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver"
jdbc_url = f"jdbc:mongodb://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}?authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1"

jar_folder = "jars_test"

jar_folder = os.path.abspath(jar_folder)

jar_files = [os.path.join(jar_folder, file) for file in os.listdir(jar_folder) if file.endswith(".jar")]

# Start the JVM with the JDBC driver JAR files
if not jpype.isJVMStarted():
    # Start the JVM with the JDBC driver JAR files
    jpype.startJVM(
        jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(),
        "-Djava.class.path={}".format(os.pathsep.join(jar_files))
    )

try:
    # Connect to MongoDB using JayDeBeApi
    conn = jaydebeapi.connect(
        driver_name,
        jdbc_url,
        [username, password],
    )
    print("Connection successful and query executed.")
    conn.close()

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
    raise e

And I got this error:
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 59 (CommandNotFound): 'no such command: 'sqlGetResultSchema'' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "no such command: 'sqlGetResultSchema'", "code": 59, "codeName": "CommandNotFound"}

I didn't find any solution for it and the assumption is that Mongo DB doesn't support this Command.
Any Suggestions and possible solutions for MongoDB connectivity using JDBC?

Seems like you are using Atlas JDBC driver. I ran into the same issue earlier today with this driver specifically.
For the moment being, try using a different JDBC driver, like https://github.com/wise-coders/mongodb-jdbc-driver - it worked for me
